# Trocar a TimeZone do DateTime.now

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Estou hospedando meu sistema em um servidor que está no EUA.

Então ao utilizar o `DateTime.Now` retorna a data e horário do EUA.

Gostaria que retornasse a data e o horário do Brasil. É possível?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Você precisa converter para o o fuso desejado, assim:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. South America Standard Time"))
```

Veja [funcionando no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tFdSfX). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/GetDateTzInfo.cs). Note que ele está hospedado em outro país mas configura o servidor com horário universal. Não importa neste caso porque a conversão pé feita em cima do horário local considerando o fuso que efetivamente está sendo usado.

Eu acredito que não mas veja se tem algum fuso mais adequado para você.

Você pode criar um método para pegar a hora local:

```
public DateTime PegaHoraBrasilia() => TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. South America Standard Time"));
```

Veja [funcionando no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RaY0YS). E [no **Coding Ground**](http://tpcg.io/oQ52av). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/GetDateWithZone.cs).

Dê o nome que achar mais adequado. E chame este método sempre que quiser o `DateTime.Now` em horário de Brasília.

Answer (score 5):

Se você não tiver acesso as configurações do servidor (para mudar o fuso horário dele) pode usar o seguinte método para converter a hora

```
public DateTime HrBrasilia()
        { 
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            TimeZoneInfo hrBrasilia = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. South America Standard Time");
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dateTime, hrBrasilia);
        }
```

Complementando você poderia adicionar o código abaixo no seu `Web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization culture="pt-BR"/> // ADICIONAR ESTA LINHA AO SEU Web.config
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Para que os formatos de data também sejam no padrão utilizado pelo Brasil.

Fontes:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397769%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749073%28v=ws.10%29.aspx
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19241815/how-to-change-the-default-timezone-of-my-asp-net-website-in-web-config-file
- http://www.devmedia.com.br/web-config-a-importancia-de-se-configurar-a-cultura/25274

Comment: Dai em todo meu código eu usaria ConverterHora(DateTime.Now), ao invés de apenas DateTime.Now ?

Comment: @DiegoZanardo fiz uma edição na resposta, como seria somente para 'DateTime.Now' o método poderia ser como a resposta acima e você chama-lo 'HrBrasilia()' (ou outro nome que quiser). O melhor Método para resolver este problema seria mesmo você ter acesso as configurações de data/hora do seu servidor e altera-las para o fuso horário que desejar.

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Isto mesmo. Embora tem um uma forma um pouco melhor de constituir o método, eu e o williamhk2 pensamos nisto juntos.

Answer (score 3):

Além da resposta do Maniero, é importante lembrar de usar `Globalization` para setar suas configurações regionais, caso seu código (e códigos de interface) precisem de configurações específicas para pt_br.

Uma alternativa simples é perguntar ao usuário qual a Time zone correta para ele e permitir que ele selecione as opções de linguagem e localização. Mas, isso depende muito do propósito do aplicativo.

Aplicações de uso genérico ou embarcadas, geralmente controlam isso ao gosto do usuário.

Link sobre Globalization:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688125.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Eu precisei fazer o mesmo, usar o DateTime.Now para obter a hora do Brasil dentro de uma função AWS Lambda.
Usei o [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/) que usa o padrão [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).

Veja um exemplo:

```
using NodaTime;

...

var zoneProvider = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Sao_Paulo"];
var instant = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(DateTime.UtcNow);
var zonedDateTime = instant.InZone(zoneProvider);
var agora = zonedDateTime.ToDateTimeOffset();
```

Para instalar:

```
PM> Install-Package NodaTime
```