# Convert.ChangeType converte data de forma errada

Tags: c#, datetime

O método `Convert.ChangeType` está convertendo a data de forma errada eu espero `24/02/2015` e vem `23/02/2015`. Alguém sabe o motivo?

Exemplo do código:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string data = @"2015-02-24T01:00:01-01:00";

            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact(data, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));//CONVERTE ERRADO
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(data));//CONVERTE ERRADO


            Console.WriteLine((DateTime?)Convert.ChangeType(data, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(DateTime?))));//CONVERT ERRADO
            Console.WriteLine((DateTime)Convert.ChangeType(data, typeof(DateTime)));//CONVERT ERRADO

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

[image: O que meu console escreve]

Comment: Você espera *24/02/2015* e está retornando *24/02/2015*, não é o certo?

Comment: Corrigido. Desculpe estou no trabalho fiz isso correndo.

Comment: Pra mim está certo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3Fd28k

Comment: @bigown, editei a pergunta para mostrar o resultado do meu console. Tem alguma idéia?

Comment: Por enquanto não, mudei para testar outras culturas mas continua ok. É provável que tenha alguma coisa com seu ambiente. Eu duvido que uma diferença de versão do .Net esteja produzindo resultados diferentes. https://dotnetfiddle.net/8bfSTH

Comment: Eu achei esse formato em XML de NFe. Infelizmente não acho mais exemplos de data nesse formato. Existe um formato padrão para data em XML?

Comment: Que eu saiba não, em tese cada um pode criar o formato que quiser. Tem um formato para a definição do XML. Mas o problema não é de formato, ele parece estar ok, tanto que eu mostrei que funciona. Precisaria descobri porque o seu .Net não está fazendo o mesmo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21989/discussion-between-reiksiel-and-bigown).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei!!!

Seguinte a data vem com essa parte: `-01:00` que quer dizer a timezone. Quando convertemos uma data ele adapta para a timezone do PC.

O programa converteu para o valor: `24/02/2015 01:00:01` na timezone -1, no meu caso, estou em SP e a timezone é -3 ele subtrai 2h e fica com o valor `23/02/2015 23:00:01`.

Comment: Claro. Eu tinha te falado que era por causa do seu ambiente. Tem a ver com isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46489/101

Comment: Dê aceite na reposta para a pergunta não ficar em aberto :-)